# Epp's proof that if a graph $G$ has a vertex of degree $k$ and $G$ is ismorphic to $G'$, then $G'$ has a vertex of degree $k$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I'm very confused by the this last paragraph shown here:

[image]

What exactly does she mean by "there are no edges incident on $g(v)$ other than the ones that are images under $g$ of edges incident on $v$"? Her $g$ function maps from $V(G) \to V(G')$, so why would an edge be an image under $g$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $g$ is a map from $V(G)$ to $V(G')$. But homomorphism gives that, if $uv$ is an edge in $G$ then $g(u)g(v)$ is an edge in $G'$. So here image of the edge $e=uv$ under $g$ refers the edge $e'=g(u)g(v)$ in $G'$.